# Socket.IO still polling after removal from project

Tags: node.js, git, sockets, socket.io

New to node, so I feel like I might be missing something trivial here:

I was using socket.io on a node.js server using express.js. I then decided I wanted to remove it from my project completely. I reverted back to an old commit before I had ever included or installed any socket.io files or dependencies.

However, now when I start my node server (`npm start`), I am now seeing a 404 error appear in my console every few seconds:

`GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCq0Mj7 404 9.697 ms - 1525`

From my understanding of git, how is these even possible?? I am switched back to a commit before I ever did anything with socket.io I can see that my code is back to the way it was. I even tried deleting the node modules and uninstalling socket.io.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running socket.io on your client. Either a browser has a window with the old HTML running, or a browser is loading a cached version of your page when you start it, or you forgot to remove the socket.io client code from your template.

You could probably pinpoint what machine it is by logging what ip address the request is coming from and the `User-Agent` header it is sending.

Comment: Not sure which one worked, but I restarted both my browser and my terminal. That seemed to do the trick. Thanks.